# Can't get LogCat to work from C / NDK

Tags: android-ndk, logcat

I'm trying to get some native code running for Android and need to do some basic debugging... but I can't get logcat to work.

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{

#define  LOG_TAG    "testjni"
#define  ALOG(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

void myMethod() {
  ALOG("This message comes from C at line %d.", __LINE__);
}
```

I have tried at least a dozen different code snippets from around the web but to no avail... as I keep getting the error message that the symbol "ANDROID_LOG_INFO" cannot be resolved.

I have added

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

to my Android.mk

Thank you in advance for any help...

Comment: Here is an simple example that worked for me: https://manski.net/2012/05/logging-from-c-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

Does it choke at compile time or run time?

Here is a [small demo NDK application](https://github.com/guycole/NativeDemo) which employs logging.  Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: It wont let me compile.

Comment: I'm assuming that it is something to do with the including of android/log.h - how can I check that this is being included properly?

Comment: If you are failing at compile time, that is a great sign it isn't being included.  Perhaps your NDK environment is not properly set up?  Can you compile and run any of the NDK examples?

Comment: I am actually using one of the NDK examples (jniHello)... and added my own code and it compiles/runs well... just not the logcat bit.